# Flyway DB Upgrader in Spring

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I've a problem with the Flyway schema upgrader for Spring. Following code exists in my servlet.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate" depends-on="dataSource">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

But how to set the migration script directory or rather whats the default directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is explained in the [excellent documentation](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/migrationSql.html):

[image: a busy cat]

If you want to alter the default directory (which is `db/migration` as shown on the picture above), I believe this should work (see: [`Flyway.setBaseDir()`](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/javadoc/com/googlecode/flyway/core/Flyway.html#setBaseDir(java.lang.String))):

```
<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate" depends-on="dataSource">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="baseDir" value="my/migrations/path"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: i've read the documentation but how can i set the baseDir property in spring? and whats the root directory?

Comment: @endian: the default directory is `db/migration`, exactly what the picture shows. The "root" directory is `src/main/resources` - the root of your CLASSPATH. In the meantime I added Spring integration example.

Comment: i added the package main.resources.db.migration but flyway prints again: Unable to find path for sql migrations: db/migration

Comment: @endian: Are you using maven? There should be a directory named `/src/main/resources` with a subdirectory `db/migration` just like the screenshot says. I am using exact same configuration and works like a charm.

Comment: @Thomasz: No, i've already read the code of Flyway.java and SqlMigrationResolver.java

Comment: com/my/package/name/my/migrations/path fixed it ;)

Comment: For newer versions it's `org.flywaydb.core.Flyway`.