# Use Spring dependency injection in domain model?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have worked with Spring MVC for a while and think about to create an application with plain Spring (Spring Boot may be). I will have few domain data objects like:
- Person
- Address
But first application version will be built without Address class. I do not know what fields will be stored in Address class. Also I want to make app with Hibernate (so Hibernate will create DB tables for instances classes). So I have options:
-Create Person class at first, without address field, but it will be incomplete, and will need tests update when Address will be in system. 
-Create Address interface and make some implementation like MockAddress or StubAddress and create a data field in Person Class with Address interface type. 
-Create Address class without any interface and fields/methods and wire it with person.

I not find good explanation for this topic, so how to use DI there or is it worth not to use it? Most articles I find about service layer wire, but not about data model objects.

Comment: consider simplifying your question description a bit so you're only involving the specifics of your question.

Comment: Actually, I not sure what I can simplify, so will left as is now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The power of dependency injection (DI) is not in the domain model; e.g., you likely won't benefit from DI in the person-to-address domain model relationship. Your persistence data model, i.e., your database + Hibernate, should maintain the domain model relationships.

Managing your application configuration, however, is a perfect place to use DI to assemble a production ready application. Configuring service layers is another great spot to use DI. Using dependency injection is well-worth your time and effort to learn, even for the most basic Spring applications like what you have described.

To get you started, [here's a simple example using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) To upgrade your database as your domain model changes, use [Flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025516/flyway-db-upgrader-in-spring).

Comment: Hi. I checked first link you give, but not see there any dependency injection in domain data object. This example great, but not answers my question. Am I miss something?  Though Flyway absolutely new for me, I'll check it tomorrow...

Comment: @Pavlo - the example does use dependency injection though it's largely hidden within the framework, except for the `@Bean` in the application...

Comment: Yes I see, it injects CustomerRepository to CommandLineRunner object. But in my question i asked about injecting from one data object to other. With your example it would be if Customer was wired with some other data model object - like Address. And the question is: should I always wire them tight (Address and and Customer), or can use DI here also? Not only when inject data object to service (e.g. CommandLineRunner  bean).

Comment: @Pavlo -- if your question is focused on whether you should use dependency injection for your person-address relationship in your domain model, the question is most likely no. I will clarify my answer.

Comment: Hi. I'm happy you understand me right. Thanks for answer :)